# Name for words that may be split into two words, regardless of space placement

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for a word that becomes two words regardless of space placement?

A trivial example would be the word "aa" which becomes the two orthographic (but identical) words "a" and "a" when cleaved in the middle.

Another example is the word "aba" which becomes the words "a" and "ba" when split after the first character, and "ab" and "a" when split after the second character.

Comment: Are you talking about disyllables?

Comment: These words could be monosylabic or polyslabic. The important factor is that you can put a space anywhere in the word and create two legitimate words.

Comment: I've edited to clarify. And I'm 99% sure the answer is "No".

Comment: Like *letterbox* which becomes "letter" and "box"? Oh, now I get it. Split the word anywhere and it still makes sense. Let terb (not a word)  ox... The answer must be "no"

Comment: Are you looking for a new word, or are you trying to remember a word that you know exists?

Comment: I think you will have difficulty finding more than about a dozen words in the English language that fit your criteria, so there's little point in coming up with a word.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's so narrowly scoped as to be of no probable use to the vast majority of members.

Comment: @HotLicks nice guess. There are 13.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, as far as I know, there is no such word.  The nearest is the palindrome, being a word, phrase or sentence that reads the same left to right and right to left:"able was I ere I saw Elba."; or "Madam, I'm Adam."  These are the best known of these.  They are only interesting enough to acquire a special word as a mild curiosity, difficult to make up but of no literary interest.

Come to think of it, "Madam" is not only a palindrome but one of your a ... what shall we call it?

> schizonyms might do; schizo (σχίζω) is the Greek word meaning ‘I split’ as in *schism*.  I cannot imagine a schizonymic poem being written.  Perhaps it could be done.  Would a reader understand it?  Now there is a thought.  It might be used for some sort of schizonymic code, to be decoded by picking out the schizonyms and fitting them together.

Surely not.

Comment: I like that: 'schizonyms.' Although 'madam' would not be one such word. Splitting after the first character, 'm' is not a word, but 'adam' is.

Comment: @user2723494 No:  ‘mad’ and ‘am’.

Comment: No, my intent was to find a word that could be split after each character and still produce two words (m+adam;ma+dam;mad+am...), otherwise, any compound word would fit the description.

Comment: @user2723494 Whatever for?

Comment: I like words that have special properties (i.e., Sequioa contains each vowel only once, and there are only about 3 words with that property). Pure curiosity. Still I appreciate your answer and up voted.

Answer (score 1):

I am concluding 'no' after a thorough search and collecting the answers provided here.

I did find some interesting names for [unique words](https://theweek.com/articles/464433/palindromes-anagrams-9-other-names-alphabetical-antics) including *ambigrams* and *antigrams*.

I wrote a program, and I found that there are only 13 such words in the English language, so @`Hot Lick`'s guess was almost exactly right.

```
Here are the words: 

AA
ABA
AHA
AHI
AI
ALA
AMA
AMI
ANA
ANANA
ITA
I
A
```